# Reload/Reset Texture2D in XNA Windowsphone

Tags: xna, windows-phone, reload, reset, texture2d

I'm manipulating a Texture2D with Texture2D.Setdata and change its color.

But i want to reset the Texture2D after a Time again, currently im having the whole Texture Datas in Memory, but now i have OutOfMemoryExceptions in my App.

I Tried this:

```
Color[] bla = new Color[thetexture.Width * thetexture.Height];
this.Content.Load<Texture2D>(".\\textures\\mytexture").GetData(bla);
thetexture.SetData(bla);
```

But it doesn't change anything, the texture just stays colored.

How can I reset the texture, so that it looks like freshly loaded, but with a small Memoryuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ContentManager` caches objects. Your call to `Load` is returning what is presumably the *same* object as your `thetexture` (the one you already modified).

You need to load a separate instance of your texture with the original data. You need a separate `ContentManager` for that. Possibly one that has been [customised](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/03/09/contentmanager-readasset.aspx) to never cache objects.

Alternately, create a `new Texture2D` object and copy the original data into that before modifying it, leaving the original untouched.